# Cannot read property forEach of undefined - d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a chart using d3js (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4339083/). Here is the problematic code:

```
d3.json("/MyController/MyAction", function (error, flare) {
    if (error) throw error;

    console.log(flare);

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});
```

The lines :

```
  root.children.forEach(collapse);
```

and

```
  d._children.forEach(collapse);
```

give error because collapse is not defined. Am I getting the error because my JSON object is not correct? Thanks.

Here is my console log :

```
{"name":"Country","children":[{"name":"City","children":[{"name":"County","children":[{"name":"Child1","size":2},{"name":"Child2","size":2},{"name":"Child3","size":2}]}]}]}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: can you post full working example where it's giving errors? This snippet works correctly in my console

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error from somewhere else, the code you posted works:

```js
var height = 10;
var root = {
  "name": "Country",
  "children": [{
    "name": "City",
    "children": [{
      "name": "County",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Child1",
        "size": 2
      }, {
        "name": "Child2",
        "size": 2
      }, {
        "name": "Child3",
        "size": 2
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
console.log(root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But it's giving the error at those lines. What should I do?

Comment: maybe if you post more of your code and more of your console output it will help

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, when I save the same JSON in a .json file, it worked...